# Finding begining and end of several patterns in Brackets using regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a sequence and a pattern with several brackets (only one level deep)

```
seq = "TTVGYDRTERDFSSADFTTVGYDRTERDFSSADFTTVGYDRTERDFSSADFTTVGYDRTERDFSSADF"
pattern = "(TT)V(GYD)"
```

Now I would like to match the pattern and get the beginning and end of the bracketed parts.
so for this example something like:

```
[(0,2), (3,6), (17,19), (20, 23), (34,36), (37,40), (51,53), (54,57)]
```

I've played around with the re package and thought I almoust had it with the

```
[reo.group(1).start(), reo.group(1).end() for reo in re.finditer( pattern, sequence )]
```

but sadly the .group(1) returns only a string and not a "Match Object". Does anyone have a good idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: "get the beginning and end of the bracketed parts" - can you please be more specific about the desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the undocumented [`MatchObject.regs`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_sre.c#l3546) for your purpose. It seems to define the match regions in a `(g0, g1, g2, ..., gn)` tuple.

```
import re

seq = "TTVGYDRTERDFSSADFTTVGYDRTERDFSSADFTTVGYDRTERDFSSADFTTVGYDRTERDFSSADF"
pattern = "(TT)V(GYD)"

result = []
for reo in re.finditer(pattern, seq):
    result.extend(reo.regs[1:])
```

Result:

```
[(0, 2), (3, 6), (17, 19), (20, 23), (34, 36), (37, 40), (51, 53), (54, 57)]
```

So the `reo.regs` for the first match look like this:

```
(Pdb) reo.regs
((0, 6), (0, 2), (3, 6))
```

Because you are only interested in the spans of the individual groups, we select all but the first 2-tuples with `reo.regs[1:]` (slice from index 1 to the end).

Since `((0, 2), (3, 6))` is still a tuple, you would end up with a list `[((s0, e0), (s1, e2)), ((s2, e2), (s3, e3)), ...]`. In order to keep the list of indices flat, I therefore [`extend`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend) a list instead of appending to it.

Comment: I knew that had to be doable somehow! nice solution, thakns! would you care to make a comment or two about this .expand function, because the help text was nor so helpful... (it just said "built in method")